# Install Mongo 3.6 on CentOS 7

Tags: mongodb, centos

I am trying to install Mongo version 3.6 on CentOS, but the installation consistently fails with the following error:

```
`https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from mongodb-org-3.6: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`
```

Here's the content of the repo file that I am using. I have copied this from the MongoDB website:

```
`[mongodb-org-3.6]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc`
```

I have looked up on many forums, but I could not find a resolution to this issue. Could you help with the installation? Let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-server-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i mongodb-org-server-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

sudo systemctl start mongod
```

### ** EDIT **

**INSTALL ADDITIONAL COMPONENTS**

```
# SHELL
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-shell-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i mongodb-org-shell-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# MONGOS
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-mongos-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i mongodb-org-mongos-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# TOOLS
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-tools-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i mongodb-org-tools-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# REMAINING BITS
wget https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i mongodb-org-3.6.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I need to pass some options to the mongo service when I start it. how can I do that in this case?

Comment: @Charanjit - use/modify the config file located at `/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: BTW - which options did you want to change?

Comment: Specifying logpath, keyFile, tlsMode tlsCertificate

Comment: Yes, all of these options are configuration items that can be specified in the config file.

Comment: You will need to restart the service after config file changes...

Comment: I need to start the mongos service, but it throws this error: **Failed to start mongos.service: Unit not found.** Do I need to do anything extra?

Comment: Hi @Charanjit - My instructions were for the mongod database engine only.  If you need other components you will need to download and install them too.  I have updated my answer above to include all the components (excluding compass).

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.6.repo` file so that you can install MongoDB directly using `yum`:

   Use the following repository file:

   ```
   [mongodb-org-3.6]
   name=MongoDB Repository
   baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
   gpgcheck=1
   enabled=1
   gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.6.asc
   ```
2. Install the MongoDB packages with the following command:

   ```
   sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-3.6.17 mongodb-org-server-3.6.17 mongodb-org-shell-3.6.17 mongodb-org-mongos-3.6.17 mongodb-org-tools-3.6.17
   ```

Comment: everything is there. I get this error **https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from mongodb-org-3.6: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat//mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`**

Comment: **Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package mongodb-org-3.6.17 available.
No package mongodb-org-shell-3.6.17 available.
No package mongodb-org-mongos-3.6.17 available.
No package mongodb-org-tools-3.6.17 available.
Nothing to do**

Comment: yum install -y mongodb-org **Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
mongodb-org-3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do**

Comment: I cleaned it up and recreate the repo file. But still seeing the same error **Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
mongodb-org-3.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do**

Comment: You can also do 
`sudo rpm -i  https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/RPMS/mongodb-org-3.6.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

Change your url by indicating CentOS 7:

```
https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.6/x86_64/
```

Comment: When I change it to the above url, I get the following error:                                                         **Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do**